# How to use public DNS in Bookwork 64bit

Tags: dns, 64-bit, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I'm trying to use [Cloudflare's public DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/) , 1.1.1.1. Configuring that in Buster was relatively easy by editing `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and replacing:

```
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

with

```
static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1
```

My Pi OS Bookworm 64bit headless installation doesn't have a `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file. How would I change the DNS in this OS?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Bookworm uses NetworkManager to manage connections, so we need to configure it to use a custom DNS.

List connections:

```
nmcli device
```

Note the relevant connection name.

```
sudo nmcli connection modify [connection-name] ipv4.dns "1.1.1.1"
sudo nmcli connection modify [connection-name] ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
sudo nmcli connection up [connection-name]
```

Those changes will be saved here: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/[connection-name].nmconnection`

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

Confirm the DNS changes:

```
nmcli device show | grep IP4.DNS
```

More details:

```
nmcli connection show [connection-name]
```

Comment: By the way, there's also `nmtui` for a TUI way of doing things in NetworkManager

Comment: @JaromandaX, nice, thank you